# Plotting histogram with text using python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a histogram in python, and add text on the right upper corner.

here I am creating and plotting the histogram:

```
sample = stats.poisson.rvs(loc = 0,mu = lamda, size = 10001)
plt.hist(sample)
pd.DataFrame(sample).hist(bins=58, 
                          figsize=(9,9),
                          edgecolor="k", linewidth=1)
```

Now, I am trying to plot the mean and median in the right upper corner:

```
plt.text(0.8, 0.9, s = 'mean = {0}'.format(round(np.mean(sample), 2)))
plt.text(0.8, 0.8, s = 'median = {0}'.format(np.median(sample)))
```

and here is the screenshot of the output:
[image]

As you can see, the x and y values of the text are coordinate values.

How can I pass relative x and y values (to place the text in the upper right corner)?

Comment: Have you tried reading out the axis limits and calculating the relative location yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify which coordinate system you want to use, otherwise it will automatically use the data coordinate system.
In your case you want to use `ax.transax`.

```
plt.text(0.8, 0.9, s = 'mean = {0}'.format(round(np.mean(sample), 2)),transform=ax.transAxes)
plt.text(0.8, 0.8, s = 'median = {0}'.format(np.median(sample)),transform=ax.transAxes)
```

I suggest you to read [this](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html)

You can also find an example in the [matplotlib text documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.text.html)